# arc length parameterization of planar curve in Matlab

Tags: differential-geometry, matlab, plane-curves

Let $\gamma (t)$ be a planar curve parameterized by time $t$. For fun, let it be a limacon. In Matlab $\gamma (t)$ looks like this.

```
% t parameterizes the limacon x=(x(t),y(t)).
h=.1; t0 = 0; T = 2*pi+h;
t = t0:h:T;
a = 1; b = .5;
% This is the cartesian version of the polar curve r = b + a*cos(theta)
x = a/2 + b*cos(t) + (a/2)*cos(2*t);
y = b*sin(t) + (a/2)*sin(2*t);
```

Assume $\gamma '(t)$ is the time-derivative of $\gamma $ and the arc length $s$ satisfies $s=\int _{t0} ^T \| \gamma '(t) \| \mathrm{d}t $.
The vector `s` below gives the distance traveled along $\gamma $ as a function of time.

```
x_t = diff(x);
y_t = diff(y);
s = cumtrapz( sqrt(x_t.^2 + y_t.^2 ) );
```

I want to reparametrize $\gamma $ in terms of arc length $s$. Basically, I want a vector which gives the time $t$ as a function of $s$. I also need this to be a numerical solution, since in general my curves are quite arbitrary (experimental data), not neat little limacons like I am playing with here. So it will probably be necessary to interpolate between values of the vector `s`.

Comment: I found a solution. As suggested, it just involved learning a little more about Matlab's interp1 function. I'll post this answer tomorrow sometime.

Comment: I suppose if a limacon can't get an upvote, nothing will :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked on this a little more, so I guess I'll take a stab at my own question. Here is our limacon again.

[image: the limacon $\gamma(t)$]

Notice what we begin with: a time parameter $t$ which runs in equal steps over the interval $[t_0,T]$, the cumulative distance $s$ traveled along the arc length at time $t$, and the Cartesian coordinates of the limacon $\gamma $ at time $t$. We set this much up in the question. What we want instead is an arc length parameter $s$ which runs in equal steps over the interval $[0,L]$, where $L$ is total arc length, together with the time $t(s)$ at $s$ and the Cartesian coordinates $\gamma (t(s))$.

Real quick, let's redo the cumulative distance $s$ traveled along the arc length with `derivative` ([File Exchange link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28920-derivative/content/derivative.m)) so that we don't lose samples.

```
x_t = derivative(x);
y_t = derivative(y);
s = cumtrapz( sqrt(x_t.^2 + y_t.^2 ) );
```

We will be using the Matlab function `interp1` in order to interpolate the timepoints $t(s_i)$ and coordinates $\gamma (t(s_i))$ which correspond to equally spaced steps $s_i$ along the arc length. Accordingly, we declare the arguments to `interp1` with the variable names given in its documentation. The vector `X` is the original $s_i$, i.e. the distance traveled along the arc length at time $t_i$. The matrix `V` has column vectors whose rows are $t_i$ (our original time parameter in equal step size), and the coordinates $\gamma (t_i)$.

```
X = s.';
V = [ t.', x.', y.' ];
```

We need to interpolate to find the time points $t(s_i)$ corresponding to equally spaced arc length steps along the curve. These equally spaced steps run from $s_0=0$ to $s_N=L$, where $L$ is the total arc length.

```
L = s(end);
s0 = s(1);
N = length(s);
Xq = linspace(s0,L,N); % equally spaced indices
```

We can verify that `s(N) == sum(diff(Xq))`, as should be the case. We use the multidimensional piece-wise linear interpolation capability of Matlab's interpolation function `interp1` to find interpolated values for time $t(s_i)$ and coordinates $\gamma (t(s_i))$ which correspond to the equally spaced steps of $s_i$ given in `Xq`.

```
Vq = interp1(X,V,Xq);
```

A call to `diff(Xq)` shows that we are moving in steps of constant arc length along $\gamma $, while a call to `diff(Vq)` shows that the time steps are no longer equal (first column). Thus, the result of our interpolation is:

- arc length $s_i$ in constant steps (`Xq`)
- corresponding timepoints $t_i$, no longer in constant steps (first column of `Vq`)
- coordinates $\gamma(t(s))$ as function of arc length (second and third columns of `Vq`)

So the arc length parametrization of the limacon $\gamma (t(s))$ is expressed in Cartesian coordinates as `xs` and `ys`.

```
xs = Vq(:,2);
ys = Vq(:,3);
```

These vectors give the position of a particle moving along $\gamma $ as a function of $s$, where $s$ increments in steps of `0.1058`. Here are the two parameterizations of the curve $\gamma $, namely $\gamma (t)$ in blue and $\gamma (t(s))$ in red.

[image: two parametrizations]

I'll have to do some more work if I want to allow periodic solutions, since the current Matlab script does not in general. To see this, just look at the distance between the last and first sample of $\gamma (t(s))$ in red above. If we were to advance one more step of `0.1058` units along the limacon we would not land on a point we already visited, even though we know limacons are $2\pi$-periodic. I think this basically amounts to choosing a different step size for $s$ than `0.1058`.

Comment: do you have any idea how to extend this method to arbitrary dimensions ?